# Как одним запросом получить все Product в категории, и связаны с ними Price определённого типа

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Подскажите как сформировать запрос, чтоб в ответ получить Queriset с аннотаций, где значением Queriset будут Product, а аннотация к каждому продукту объект Price по указанному типу? Есть такие модели:

```
class Category(MPTTModel):
    """
    Базовая модель категории и под категории.
    """
    name = models.CharField(
        _("Name of category"),
        max_length=500,
    )
    slug = models.SlugField(
        _("Slug of category name"),
        max_length=1000,
        unique=True,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )

class Product(models.Model):
    """Модель описывает в себе все свойства товара."""
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        "products.Category",
        verbose_name=_("Category of product"),
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )

class Price(models.Model):
    """Модель описывает в себе цену на продукт. Есть связь с моделью Product."""
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        "products.Product",
        verbose_name=_("Product"),
        related_name="product_prices",
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    # Тип цены согласно которой формируется цифра стоимости
    price_type = models.CharField(
        _("Price type name"),
        max_length=300,
    )
```

Comment: Не понятен ваш вопрос. Какой qs вам нужно получить и что такое  Queriset с аннотаций, где значением Queriset будут Product, а аннотация к каждому продукту объект Price указанному по типу?

Comment: Я делал вот такой запрос Price.objects.filter(product__category__slug=kwarg.get("slug"), price_type=conntract.price_type).select_related("product"). В ответ получаю все цени, и к ним прикреплены все товары. Меня интересует как сделать запрос с стороны Product?

Comment: Попробуйте `Product.objects.filter(category__slug=kwarg.get("slug"), product_prices__price_type=conntract.price_type).prefetch_related("product_prices")`

Comment: К сожалению так не работает. qs = Product.objects.filter(category__slug=kwarg.get("slug"), product_prices__price_type=conntract.price_type).prefetch_related("product_prices")     обращаясь qs[0].product_prices возвращается значение <django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_reverse_many_to_one_manager.<locals>.RelatedManager object at 0x7f92e8e3bac0>

Comment: С помощью sql я делаю вот такой запрос SELECT p.name, pp.value as price FROM products_product p LEFT JOIN products_price pp on p.id = pp.product_id WHERE pp.price_type='Цена 3' . Как етот запрос сделать с помощью django ORM?

Answer (score 1):

Вот правильное решение:

```
Product.objects.filter(category__slug=kwargs.get("slug_name"),
  product_prices__price_type=selected_price_type, ).annotate(
    product_price=F("product_prices__value")).values("id", "name", "slug", "description", "article",
      "in_stock", "weight", "package_count", "income_date",
        "code", "product_price").order_by("name")
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]